# Proving the limit of a sequence $\in$ $[0, \infty)$ if the sequence is within the field $\in$ $[0, \infty)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I've been working on this question for the past 30mins and haven't got anywhere, I have an idea on how to do it, but I was wondering if someone could just start me off because I really want to learn how to do these types of questions by myself, just struggling on how to start it, I do realise it's done by contradiction, etc and further steps just need the initial ones to get an idea. Any help would GREATLY be appreciated!! Thanks :)

Question:

Suppose $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a convergent sequence and $a_n \in [0, \infty)$ for all $n$. Prove that the limit of $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ lies in $[0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof doesn't require contradiction.  A sketch of a valid proof:

1. Show that convergent sequences are bounded.
2. Show that, since $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent, it's bounded by some $M$, so we can consider $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ taking values in $[0,M]$.
3. Argue that $[0,M]$ is closed, so it contains its limit points, so $\lim a_n\in [0,M]\subseteq[0,\infty)$.

The first one may take some thought if you haven't seen the proof before.    The proof is hidden below, but I encourage you to prove it yourself.

> Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a convergent sequence where $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$.  Then, let $\epsilon >0$.  We have that there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have that $|a_n-L| < \epsilon$.  $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ took on finitely many values before this, so denote $M_1 = \max\{|a_1|,\dots,|a_{N-1}|\}$, and let $M_2 = |L| + \epsilon$.  We have that $M = \max\{M_1,M_2\}$ is a bound for $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, as for $n < N$ we have that $|a_n| < M_1$, and for $n\geq N$ we have that $|a_N| < |L|+\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I get everything, except in the hidden proof you did $M_1 = {|a_1|,...,|a_{N-1}|}$ why is it N-1? It's probably really simple but I'm missing it!

Comment: We have that for all $n\geq N$, that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$.  We can bound this easily.  It's possible that $|a_n-L|\not<\epsilon$ for $n < N$.  These $n < N$ are precisely $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{N-1}$, so we take the max of all of their magnitudes.

Answer (score 0):

Try a proof by contradiction. Suppose it converges to a negative number $\epsilon$. Then is it possible to have an $N$ st $\forall n > N$, $|a_n - \epsilon| < |\epsilon|/2$, if all $a_n$ are non-negative?

Comment: $|a_n-\epsilon|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is never true since $\epsilon$ is negative. That's not exactly what you have to show, but the idea is good.

Comment: No, it's not, the edit is ok though.

Answer (score 0):

The interval contains all its limit points. In particular it contains all limit points of a countable subset.